# Verification of proof that two sequences converge to the same value

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Consider the sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfying the following properties:
>
> 1. $0<y_1<x_1$
> 2. $x_{n+1}=(x_n+y_n)/2$ for all $n\ge2$
> 3. $y_{n+1}=2x_ny_n/(x_n+y_n)$ for all $n\geq 2$

I would like to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\sqrt{x_1y_1}$. Here's my proof. Is it correct?

> $x_2$ is the arithmetic mean of $x_1$ and $y_1$, while $y_2$ is their harmonic mean. Since the former mean is always larger, $x_1>x_2>y_2>y_1>0$. By extension:
>   $$x_1>x_2>x_3>\dots x_n>x_{n+1}>y_{n+1}>y_n>\dots y_3>y_2>y_1>0$$
>   Thus $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are monotone and bounded; by the monotone convergence theorem they converge to a finite limit.
>
> Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$. Then $x=(x+y)/2$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so $x=y=L$.
>   Moreover, $x_1y_1=x_2y_2=x_3y_3=\dots=x_ny_n=x_{n+1}y_{n+1}=L^2$, so $L=\sqrt{x_1y_1}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Is your condition for $y_{n+1}$ right (as it is written, $y_{n+1}$ is just $2$)?

Comment: @CarlosIsraelJrl It was correct how I wrote it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok. Now it is correct.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure that I preserved your meaning.  If you click on "edit" you can see the syntax I used to format your post.

Comment: @lulu Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  Some hints to get you started:  Show that $0<y_n<x_n\forall n$, show that $x_{n+1}y_{n+1}=x_ny_n$, deduce that $x_n$ is decreasing and $y_n$ is increasing.  Can you finish from there?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the hints! I will analyze how to use them.

Comment: @lulu Other embarrassing question. I do not understand how the sequences go from term to term. Can you explain me that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Yours is an example of a "double recursion", that is to say you need both values to move along.  For example, we see that $x_2=\frac {x_1+y_1}2$ and $y_2=\frac {2x_1y_1}{x_1+y_1}$.

Comment: As a suggestion:  program this in whatever language you like.  Pick some initial conditions and experiment.

Comment: @lulu Brilliant idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46481/discussion-between-beginner-and-lulu).

Comment: I don't like to go into chat rooms, sorry.  If you make some progress on the question...edit your post to reflect that.  I'll comment on your work, or post a full solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both sequences converge, let $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$ and $y=\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n= \lim_{n \to \infty} y_{n+1}$, note that taking the limit on both sides of the recursive equations above, we have $x=(x+y)/2$ and $y = 2xy/(x+y)$, so plugging one into the other, we get $$x=\frac{x+y}{2}=\frac{2xy}{2x}=y,$$ as we wanted.

Now, the recursive equations also tell you that $x_{n+1}=(x_n+y_n)/2$, so $y_{n+1}= \frac{2x_ny_n}{x_n+y_n}=\frac{2x_ny_n}{2x_{n+1}}$, that is, $$x_{n+1}y_{n+1}=x_ny_n = \cdots = x_1y_1.$$ Taking limits and since $x=y$, we get $y^2=x_1y_1$, so $y = \sqrt{x_1y_1}$ (note $x_n, y_n >0$).

The only thing left to do to make it all work is prove that both sequences actually converge. I'll leave this up to you!

Comment: I think there's a mistake: you've $\frac{2xy}{2y} \ne y$

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks!